# Geopaparazzi does not recognize spatialite vector data

Tags: spatialite-gui

I have failed to use geometry data from a spatialite database in geopaparazzi.

I have tried following steps as described in http://jgrasstechtips.blogspot.de/2015/01/how-to-properly-create-spatialite-data.html

1. downloading and installing of spatialite_gui as described above from http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-amd64-prev/ (but only found 1.8.0 dev instead of 1.7.1) for windows (can you tell me where i  can download 1.7.1 windows binaries ??? / how to compile from source files   ???). (Using Spatialite_gui 1.8.0. is always with Error “SQLite SQL error: no such module VirtualElementary”). 
   Using Spatialite_gui 2.0.0. devel is without error, but the produced data as described follwoung cannot be imported to geopaparazzi too.
2. creating a new empty database on “Desktop”
3. importing a shp-file (Polygon) to the database (GeomColumnName “Geometry”, SRID “4326”, Encoding “UTF-8”,”With Spatial Index *R-Tree”, GeometryType: Automatic (User specified-polygon failed too), PrimaryKeyColumn: Automatic (User specified-PKUID failed too)
4. Select UpdateLayerStatistics()-command
5. check geometry (in spatialite gui 2.0.0) -> result “valid”
6. close spatialite_gui and copy the file to mobile device samsung galaxy s4: “/storage/extSdCard/maps/...sqlite”
7. with geopaparazzi: OpenMapView:SpatialiteDataView:’+’: /storage/extSdCard/maps/...sqlite-> ERROR: **“The selected file doesn’t contain any vector data:....**”
   (with qgis 2.14 for example it is no problem to import the data from the geodatabase (type: polygon, SRID: 4326, geomColumn: “geometry”))

What is wrong preparing the vector data for geopaparazzi ? Is there a workaround ?

Comment: Which version of geopap are you using?

Comment: Geopaparazzi 5.0.1

Comment: Geopaparazzi 5.0.2